# C++: How do I produce the 'nth' line of Pascal's Triangle?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, binomial-coefficients

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,k,i,x;
    cout << "Enter a row number for Pascal's Triangle: ";
    cin >> n; 
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        x=1;
        for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
        {
            cout << x << '\t';
            x = x * (i - k) / (k + 1);
        }
    cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I change this so that it only displays the nth line instead of the whole triangle? TIA.

Comment: Use binomial coefficient calculation

Comment: You just copied someone else's code from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/56615/). And without trying to understand it, you want people to modify it for you to fit your homework assignment. If you did try to understand it, you'd see that the change is trivial.

Comment: @interjay: that sounds bad, but I guess you're right. It's really soo trivial... shame on you, user<whatever>! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the outer loop:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a row number for Pascal's Triangle: ";
    cin >> n; 
    int x = 1;
    for (int k = 0; k <= n; k++)
    {
        cout << x << '\t';
        x = x * (n - k) / (k + 1);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `cout << x << '\t';` to

```
if(i == n) cout << x << '\t';  // Print only last line (i = n)
```

And `cout << endl;` to

```
if(i == n) cout << endl;  // Print after only last line (i = n)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is an efficient way to generate the `n`th row of Pascal's triangle.

Start the row with 1, because there is 1 way to choose 0 elements.

For the next term, multiply by `n` and divide by 1. That's because there are `n` ways to choose 1 item.

For the next term, multiply by `n-1` and divide by 2. There are `n*(n-1)` ways to choose 2 items, and 2 ways to order them.

For the next term, multiply by `n-2` and divide by 3. There are `n*(n-1)*(n-2)` ways to choose 3 items, and 2*3 ways to order them.

And so on.

We stop once we have multiplied by 1 and divided by `n`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int n;
  cout << "Enter a row number for Pascal's Triangle: ";
  cin >> n; 
  int x = 1;
  cout << x;
  for (int a = n, b = 1; b <= n; --a, ++b) {
    x = x * a / b;
    cout << ' ' << x;
  } 
  cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter value of nth line

```
int i =nth Line;
for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
{
    count<<fact(i)/(fact(k)*fact(i-k))<<"\t";
}


int fact(int a)
{
    int j=1;
    for(int i=a;i>1;i--)
    {
        j*=a;
        a--;
    }
    return j;
}
```

Value of `i` start from `0`
For `i=6`

Output will be 1 6 15 20 15 6 1

Comment: This works but is one order of magnitude less efficient than possible due to the double loop.